# Clicking parent "li" element needs to open underlaying "ul"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

People,

I have a problem of which I will first paste code before explaining.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $a = $('ul li a');
  $b = $('ul ul');
  $a.on("click", function() {
    $b.slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Artists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Artists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Artists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Artists</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I need the `li` to recognize if it has a `ul` and `slideToggle` it if it has.
And when clicking on another `li` with a `ul` the previous dropdown closes.

I have absolutely no clue how i'm going to accomplish this !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Your HTML doesn't make sense. You've got a nested `<ul>` that isn't inside a `<li>`. The first `<li>` should wrap the Artists href as well as the entire `<ul>...</ul>`

Comment: Instead of `$b.slideToggle(500)` do `$(this).find('ul').slideToggle(500)` assuming your html is valid which it currently is not. By the way you formatted this, it could be a typo

Comment: as @Soviut points that is invalid HTML

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/9Lpm5dh5/

Comment: Azim make it an answer and i'll upvote !

Comment: Yes, please stop answering questions in comments!

Comment: Ok. I've added answer. @Raymond

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of small changes. I needed to nest the inner ul and simplified the selectors a little. To make it better you could drop the anchor tags and just click the li to so you don't need to traverse up to the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $link = $('ul li a')

  $link.on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle(500);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Artists</a>
        <!-- I had to nest the ul inside the li -->
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: but does this close the previous dropdown ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are referring to. Clicking the link will slideToggle the next sibling that is an unordered list

Comment: I understand that, but is there anyway that when I click another link, the previously clicked link which is expanded will close

Comment: No the inner list must be related to the anchor that was clicked. You could close all open ul's with `$('ul ul').slideUp()` before opening the clicked element

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('#navigation ul li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#navigation > nav > ul ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Artists</a>
        <ul style="display:none;">
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Artists</a>
        <ul style="display:none;">
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Artists</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```